# Doctrine Mongo ODM Duplicate Search

Tags: mongodb, symfony, zend-framework2, doctrine

I currently have a mongo shell command to run a duplicate search in a mailing list collection:

```
var duplicates = [];

db.mailing_entries.aggregate([
  { $group: { 
    _id: { full_name: "$full_name", business: "$business", address_line_1: "$address_line_1", postal_code: "$postal_code" }, 
    dups: { $addToSet: "$_id" },
    count: { $sum: 1 } 
  }}, 
  { $match: { 
    count: { $gt: 1 } 
  }}
])
.result          
.forEach(function(doc) {
doc.dups.shift();
doc.dups.forEach( function(dupId){ 
    duplicates.push(dupId);
    }
) 

});
printjson(duplicates);
```

The shell code is working perfectly for me, however, after much searching, I cannot find a way to properly translate to Doctrine Mongo ODM using a map reduce function, or any other method.

I'm currently using the Doctrine Mongo ODM module integrated with Zend Framework 2.

I have searched far and wide but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Underlying `doctrine/mongodb` package introduced [aggregation builder](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb/pull/213) in version 1.2 and while they're no docs written as of yet you can take a look at examples in linked pull request and take advantage of your IDE's autocompletion.

We aim to allow hydrating results of aggregate results into documents [in ODM](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/pull/1263) but feature is not ready yet and for now you need to obtain builder like this (supposing `MailingEntry` is your mapped document)

```
$builder = $documentManager->getDocumentCollection(MailingEntry::class)->createAggregationBuilder();
```